# Tourist Schengen visa dates do not match itinerary

Tags: visas, schengen, tourist-visas, spain, hungary

I have applied my Schengen visa from Spanish embassy from 31st May to 10th June.
My itinerary is mentioned as follows :

1. 31st May to 02 Jun - Budapest, Hungary
2. 2nd Jun to 6th Jun - Spain
3. 7th Jun to 10th Jun - Greece

I have submitted every flight tickets and accommodation from 31st may onwards.
Today, I have got the tourist visa from 02nd Jun to 01 July. My questions are :-

1. My port of entry is Hungary and that too on 31st May. Can I somehow extend my existing visa start date from 02nd Jun to 31st may?
2. If not, ideally what shall I do in this case?

Comment: Have you contacted the embassy that issued your visa?

Comment: Contact the consulate immediately. Do not delay even a minute. You should have received a paper with your passport, explaining that you received the visa, and telling who to contact if you find an error.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since Michael Hampton didn't turn his correct comment into an answer, let me: Contact the consulate immediately. Do not delay even a minute. You should have received a paper with your passport, explaining that you received the visa, and telling who to contact if you find an error.